# convert bunch of images to black and white with overwritting existing images

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to convert a bunch of images (about 1000) to black and white
I used the following code:

```
convert *.bmp -monochrome ./*.bmp
```

but it produces new images. for example, I have file1.bmp, file2.bmp and etc. and it converts them to file1-1.bmp file2-2.bmp and so on. I need the exact same name for images so I prefer to overwrite the existing one. any suggestion.
Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use the [mogrify](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) tool - *"This tool is similar to magick convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option) with any changes you request."*

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69607886/7552

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in linux, you might want to try this from the command line

```
for i in *.bmp ; do convert $i -monochrome -write $i ; done
```